# US Census ZCTA shape attribute table: shapeids with suffixes

Tags: zip-codes

What does it mean (i.e. what situation is being addressed) when the attribute table for the ZCTA shapes contains two shapeids for a given GEOID10 (e.g. 10307, Staten Island) each having a numerical suffix, but there is no shapeid for the GEOID10 without a suffix:

10696 -- does not exist
10696.0
10696.1

The data in the rows are identical.

```
shapeid ZCTA5CE10   GEOID10 CLASSFP10   MTFCC10 FUNCSTAT10  ALAND10 AWATER10    INTPTLAT10  INTPTLON10
10696.0 10307   10307   B5  G6350   S   5085103 17221   40.5091830000   -74.2377853000
10696.1 10307   10307   B5  G6350   S   5085103 17221   40.5091830000   -74.2377853000
```